# Difference between AccessDeniedHandler and ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I am trying to implement a *custom* `CommonExceptionHandler` class in my project. I searched on google there are multiple methods to achieve it. The two most common I found are above one.

Please help me , When I should use `AccessDeniedHandler` (*Interface*) and `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` (*Class*)?.

Do they make any difference when I enabled Security configuration in the project?

Answer (score 3):

To make things clear there isn't any relation between `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and `AccessDeniedHandler`. The 1st one is used to centralized the handling of most common exceptions raised by Spring MVC. It provides about 17 protected methods that you can override to customize the response after the exception. You can find more details at its javadoc: [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html)

And example of usage:

```java
@ControllerAdvice // or @RestControllerAdvice
public class CommonExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
   ...
}
```

Regarding the 2nd one `AccessDeniedHandler` as indicated on its javadoc: [AccessDeniedHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html): `Handles an access denied failure.` An access denied exception is raised when someone try to access a resource which she/he/it is not allowed to access to it.

Now if your question is:

- Can your `CommonExceptionHandler` also handle `AccessDeniedHandler` exception?

Yes by doing this:

```java
@ControllerAdvice // or @RestControllerAdvice
public class CommonExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
   ...
}
```

But I'll suggest you to handle security exception in another class like:

```java
public class CommonSecurityExceptionHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to implement a *custom* `CommonExceptionHandler` class in my project.

`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` is more preferred because it can handle any *sql*, *javax validation* ,*http method*  and any *custom exception* too. It gives you capability to customize error message with status code. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846360/recommended-way-of-dealing-with-spring-hibernate-sql-errors/50850529#50850529) is an example how you can configure you custom error handler.

As *per documentation*: `AccessDeniedHandler` can handle only exception of the `AccessDeniedException` type. Based on above mentioned link, you can handle `AccessDeniedException` by just following new method.

```java
@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedHandler.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
public Map<String, String> handleAccessDeninedException(AccessDeniedHandler ex) {
   // write your own logic to return user friendly response 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Happy Coding.