# Is there a simpler exception handling technique for Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have read about controller based exceptions using @ExceptionHandler.

I have read about global exception handling using @ControllerAdvice.

I have also read about extending HandlerExceptionResolver for more in-depth exception handling.

However, what I would ideally like to do is be able to throw a global exception with parameters that dictate a JSON response returned to the client, at any layer in my application.

For instance:

```
throw new CustomGlobalException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORISED, "This JWT Token is not Authorised.")

throw new CustomGlobalException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "This JWT Token is not valid.")
```

This would then return a JSON response based on the model I've created, along with the status, such as :

```
{
    "success" : "false",
    "message" : "This JWT Token is not Authorised."
}
```

And for this to be returned as a REST response from my controller.
Is something like this possible? Or Do I have to go through the process of making custom error exceptions for everything as described in the documentation.

To clarify, I require the exception to interrupt whatever the ongoing process is, perhaps fetching data from the database, and immediately return the given exception to the client. I have a web mvc setup.

---

Further details:

```
 @ControllerAdvice
 @RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleCustomException(CustomException ex,
                                                    WebRequest request) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    response.put("message", ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, ex.getCode());
}
}
```

Exception thrown here:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain
        filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    logger.debug("Filtering request for JWT header verification");

    try {
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

        logger.debug("JWT Value: {}", jwt);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            String username = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

            UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    (userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        } else {
            logger.error("No Valid JWT Token Provided");
                            throw new CustomException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "No Valid JWT Token Provided");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my post on how to handle exception [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846360/recommended-way-of-dealing-with-spring-hibernate-sql-errors/50850529#50850529), you can write your own handler something like this,

```
class CustomGlobalException {
    String message;
    HttpStatus status;
}

@ExceptionHandler(CustomGlobalException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleCustomException(CustomGlobalException ex,
            WebRequest request) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    response.put("success", "false");
    response.put("message", ex.getMessage());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, ex.getStatus());
}
```

Code mentioned above will handle *CustomGlobalException* occurred any layer of code.

Comment: This is ideal however it doesn't get thrown back to the client. In other words, if I set this up and I throw a CustomGlobalException, the information will be logged but the remainder of the function will continue executing.

Comment: > remainder of the function will continue executing. 
can you elaborate more?

Comment: User sends a request to my rest backend. Passes through the controller, calls the service layer. The service layer finds a problem, throws a CustomException. At this point the exception is logged. But the method continues and returns data to the user when it should have returned the error immediately.

Comment: No. The way I've provided it will not execute rest of the code. In this case method execution will stop and error will return to client. User would see o/p of _return new ResponseEntity<>(response, ex.getStatus());_ in case of error. Note: This way of handling exception I'm using in my project and it worked as I stated. If it does not work, please drop a code which you are trying. I would love to see..

Comment: I have included more detail. The response I get is a 200 with the data request by the user, even if no authentication is provided.

Comment: Ok. I checked in my project. Infect there is a similar situation when I need to validate client credential. It is working as I explain. I saw your code. I request you to do following change and check again. Change your _GlobalExceptionHandler_ as mentioned below.

@RestControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
public class GlobalExceptionHandler  extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
}

and use _CustomException_ in _@ExceptionHandler(CustomGlobalException.class)_ (in given code snippet)

Comment: Still no luck... Any chance you have a public repo? Also, is there any other config requirements maybe, i.e. setting ExceptionHandler in web.xml or something alike?

Comment: No. I don’t have. If you have code in public repo then let me know url. I will folk a branch out of that and will do all necessary changes.

Comment: I've created demo project for you and its working as expected. Here is a link https://github.com/shauank/spring-boot/tree/master/demo

Comment: I simply had been catching the exception higher up (facepalm). You really went above and beyond Shaunak, thank you...

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't exactly do what you want to achieve, but the simplest way of doing almost what you want (and is cleaner, IMO), is to simply define an exception like the following:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class UnauthorizedException extends RuntimeException {
    public UnauthorisedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Now every time such an exception is thrown (not returned) from a controller method (directly or indirectly), you'll get a response such as

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-06-24T09:38:51.453+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "This JWT Token is not Authorised.",
    "path": "/api/blabla"
}
```

And of course the actual status code of the HTTP response will also be 401.

You can also throw a `ResponseStatusException`, which is more generic and allows you to use the same exception type and pass the status as argument. But I find it less clean.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I also agree, I dislike passing the status as a parameter and leaving the actual error exception to be stagnant. I will look into this, thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue however, perhaps I am being unclear. I would like, at any point in my code, to throw an UnauthorisedException, and the current process to be interrupted and the exception to be immediately returned to the client. However this does not cause that either, I just get an exception thrown then it continues executing anyway.

Comment: If it continues executing, it means you're catching the exception somehow. Don't, and let the exception bubble up until Spring catches it and sends the above JSON to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Since Spring 5 and Above, a ResponseStatusException (spring framework provided) would be better. 
Please refer to [spring-response-status-exception](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception)