# @exceptionhandler not working in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am a beginner in Spring REST and was implementing the exception handling in Spring REST. Following is the Controller code which is throwing a custom exception

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllCountries", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public Country getCountries() throws CountryNotFoundException{

    throw new CountryNotFoundException();

    //List<Country> listOfCountries = countryService.getAllCountries();
    // return listOfCountries;
}

@ExceptionHandler(CountryNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e)
{
    ErrorMessage error = new ErrorMessage("Custom handler message "+e.toString(), req.getRequestURI());
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(error,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

}
```

Despite this the handler is not executing and I am getting the below exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.arpit.java2blog.exception.CountryNotFoundException
```

Can someone please let me know are there any other configurations which need to be taken care of for the handler to execute?

EDIT: When I change the parameter for ResponseEntity to String then it works but not with ErrorMessage. Why is this behaviour happening?

Comment: Try changing your return type to String.

Comment: I guess `CountryNotFoundException` is not a `RuntimeException`

Comment: Could you also try to e.g do the following to check wether your exeptions is being thrown using a couple of different input params? Such as :
`ResponseEntity<String> handleCountryNotFound(CountryNotFoundException e){ return ResponseEntity.status(404).entity("not found").build()}`and then see if it is being called/captured at all?

Comment: Have you defined `CountryNotFoundException` to extend `Exception`?

Comment: @DforTye no it extends RuntimeException..

Comment: @vegaasen it is getting handled when i change the errormessage to string. Why is this happening with errormessage then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class ErrorMessage {

    @JsonProperty
    private final String message;

    @JsonProperty
    private final String requestURI;

    public ErrorMessage(String message, String requestURI) {
        this.message = message;
        this.requestURI = requestURI;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. In all the examples I have come across I didn't see such annotations for handlers. Is this version specific of spring?

Comment: No, It isn't version specific. Spring tries to convert `ResponseEntity<?>` to response using `HttpMessageConverter`. To tell Jackson that `ErrorMessage` can be serialized to json we use `@JsonProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008530/is-there-a-simpler-exception-handling-technique-for-spring/51008726#51008726) on exception handling. I've created sample project for more detailed reference which can found [here](https://github.com/shauank/spring-boot/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/MyExceptionHandler.java)

Comment: thanks for your answer. When i change the parameter of ResponseEntity to string instead of a custom error class, it runs properly. But for custom error message parameter it does not. can you please let me know why?